# Nodejs Promise inside switch case giving error

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I tried various ways mentioned on stackoverflow from similar questions but still unable to resolve the issue. I have a plain function (not a async function) which contains various switch cases. I have a separate function which either resolves or rejects. Eg-

```
function Student (req) {
const id = req.id
const count = req.num
for (i=0;i<num,i++)
{
switch(id){
case 'a':
feesPaid=true
break;

case 'b':
const a = await getStudent (id) // gives error under getStudent that unexpected token eslint

getStudent (id).then((result)=>{
if(result.reciept){
feesPaid=true
}else{
feesPaid=false. // Returning pending promise which doesn't return anything, tried return feesPaid as well
}
}). catch (e)...
break;
}
}
}
```

I cannot make this function for some reason, is there any way I can return feesPaid value? Seems it doesn't update anything or any checks. feesPaid value is necessary, as it's used for further calculation. Please help.

Comment: you cannot use `await` if its not in an async function

Comment: Yes I know, that's why using a conventional method .then, but it returns pending promise

Comment: you have to embrace the async nature of nodejs. once you use async paradigm like promises, async await, callbacks you can never go back to synchronous code.

Comment: you have to do `student().then(...)` to run it.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use ``async function Student``? Otherwise, you could just do that, and modify any existing calling code to also use async/await.

Comment: You should format your code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Yes @Take-Some-Bytes, I can't make the function async as it will affect other code blocks.

Comment: Yes @Aritra Chakraborty , as you see in the question, I've already mentioned that even doing a .then(), it doesn't return/update feesPaid variable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to fix this:

1. Changing the function to an `async function`.
2. Returning a Promise.
3. Making your function accept a callback.

No matter what you do, it will always affect other code blocks.

Using `.then()` won't work because the function will return long before the Promise resolves. Returning just `feesPaid` won't work because the Promise hasn't finished before `feesPaid` is assigned a value.

The easiest solution to your problem is to just modify your function to utilize `async/await`, and modify all effected code to utilize `async/await` as well.